# Django migrate fails when creating new table

Tags: django, django-models

We are fairly new to Django.  We we have an app and a model.  We'd like to add an 'Category' object to our model.  We did that, and then ran 'python manage.py makemigrations'.

We then deploy our code to a server running the older code, and run 'python manage.py migrate'.  This throws 2 pages of exceptions, finishing with 'django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'reporting.contact_category' doesn't exist")'

This seems to be looking at our models.py.  If we comment out Category from our model, and all references to it, the migration succeeds.

I thought that the point of migrations is to make the database match what the model expects, but this seems to require that the model match the database before the migration.

We clearly are doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` on the server?

Comment: We ran 'makemigrations', and then checked in the migration file.  We then checked out the code on the server and did 'migrate';  I have tried running 'makemigrations' on the server, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you skipped some migration in the server, so now you are missing some tables (I have been in that situation. Ensure **migrations** directories are on your **.gitignore**. You CAN NOT check in migrations files, you have to run `makemigrations`  on the server). This can be solved by tracing back up to the point the database and models files match, but it is a risky process if it is your production database, so you should make a full backup before proceeding, and try the process on a different computer before.

This would be my advice:

1. Delete migration files from the server.
2. Comment the models that rise the error.
3. Set the server's migration history to the point the
   database is, using `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` (this will update the migration files without actually attempting to modify the database).
4. Uncomment the models that raise the error.
5. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

If, after you comment the models that raise the exception, you get a different exception, you have to keep on commenting and attempting again. Once a migrations succeeds, you can uncomment all commented models and make an actual migration.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to run `python manage.py makemigrations` if you made changes to the `models.py` then run `python manage.py makemigrations`

Both commands **must** be run on the same server with the same database

Comment: So, the workflow is:
- create new model
- commit
- checkout on server
- makemigrations
-migrate?

We currently:
- create new model
- makemigrations
- commit migration file
- checkout
- migrate

Comment: Nope.  Ran 'makemigrations' on the server, and still get the exception.

Comment: you don't need to make migrations and migrate on the same server. If your migrations are up to date in your code, migrate should works on your server. It generally fails when you made changes in your DB with migrations files that have been deleted or changed. The easiest solution is to rebuild the DB. Did you delete migrations files that could have done some job in the db ?